# Adding header and footer info to the printed output from a WebBrowser WITHOUT touching the registry

Tags: c#, html, css, windows, browser

Background info: C#, Visual Studio 2010, Target: Windows XP and up

I have a requirement to add classification info to the top and bottom of every page that is printed from a `System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser` object. Currently we have a HTML document which is loaded into a `WebBrowser`, and then printed with the `WebBrowser.ShowPrintDialog()` function. I need to somehow add banners to the top and bottom of **every** page being printed with the classification type centered.

I have seen mention of a method which involves modifying registry settings, but this is not an option in my case. I have also tried using the following CSS code, but it seems that `WebBrowser` does not work with `position: fixed`.

CSS:

```
@media screen
{
    div#ClassificationTop
    {
        display: none;
    }
    div#ClassificationBottom
    {
        display: none;
    }
}
@media print
{
    div#ClassificationTop
    {
        display: block;
        position: fixed;
        top: 0;
    }
    div#ClassificationBottom
    {
        display: block;
        position: fixed;
        bottom: 0;
    }
}
```

and in the `<body>`:

```
<div id="ClassificationTop">UNCLASSIFIED
</div>
<div id="ClassificationBottom">UNCLASSIFIED
</div>
```

So, being that neither of these methods work (registry workaround or CSS `position: fixed`), does anyone know of anything else I could try?

Let me know if the question is unclear or requires more info.

Answer (score 0):

The API for printing from the webbrowser control technically can support this, if you can figure out the syntax for C# for doing this. Microsoft has a KB article "[How to print custom headers and footers for a WebBrowser control in Internet Explorer](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/267240)"

In that article, it is clarified that the third parameter to the ExecWB method can be specified to contain a SAFEARRAY containing custom headers and footers.

Here is a selected part of the code example from the knowledge base article converted to C# syntax. It's not fully working code, but it should help point you in the right direction:

```
    SAFEARRAYBOUND[] psabBounds = Arrays.InitializeWithDefaultInstances<SAFEARRAYBOUND>(1);
    SAFEARRAY psaHeadFoot;

    // Initialize header and footer parameters to send to ExecWB().
    psabBounds[0].lLbound = 0;
    psabBounds[0].cElements = 3;
    psaHeadFoot = SafeArrayCreate(VT_VARIANT, 1, psabBounds);

    VARIANT vHeadStr = new VARIANT();
    VARIANT vFootStr = new VARIANT();
    VARIANT vHeadTxtStream = new VARIANT();
    int rgIndices;

    VariantInit(vHeadStr);
    VariantInit(vFootStr);
    VariantInit(vHeadTxtStream);

    // Argument 1: Header
    vHeadStr.vt = VT_BSTR;
    vHeadStr.bstrVal = SysAllocString("This is my header string.");

    // Argument 2: Footer
    vFootStr.vt = VT_BSTR;
    vFootStr.bstrVal = SysAllocString("This is my footer string.");


    // Argument 3: IStream containing header text. Outlook and Outlook 
    // Express use this to print out the mail header.   
    if ((sMem = (string)CoTaskMemAlloc(512)) == null)
    {
        goto cleanup;
    }
    // We must pass in a full HTML file here, otherwise this 
         // becomes corrupted when we print.
    sMem = "<html><body><strong>Printed By:</strong> Custom WebBrowser Host 1.0<p></body></html>\0";

    rgIndices = 0;
    SafeArrayPutElement(psaHeadFoot, rgIndices, (object)(vHeadStr));
    rgIndices = 1;
    SafeArrayPutElement(psaHeadFoot, rgIndices, (object)(vFootStr));
    rgIndices = 2;
    SafeArrayPutElement(psaHeadFoot, rgIndices, (object)(vHeadTxtStream));

    //NOTE: Currently, the SAFEARRAY variant must be passed by using
            // the VT_BYREF vartype when you call the ExecWeb method.
    VARIANT vArg = new VARIANT();
    VariantInit(vArg);
    vArg.vt = VT_ARRAY | VT_BYREF;
    vArg.parray = psaHeadFoot;
    hr = webOC.ExecWB(OLECMDID_PRINT, OLECMDEXECOPT_DONTPROMPTUSER, vArg, null);
```